# Error: EACCESS, permission denied at Object.fs.mkdirSync

Tags: node.js, bash, yeoman, meanjs, yeoman-generator

Getting this error when trying to install meanjs:crud-module

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/opt/mean/public/modules/trees'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:751:18)
at Function.sync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-meanjs/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:71:13)
at yeoman.generators.NamedBase.extend.renderModule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-meanjs/crud-module/index.js:87:8)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-meanjs/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:395:14
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:358:17)
```

I've basically chown/chmod every folder on my server, and I've uninstalled/reinstalled yo using sudo npm and -g several different times. Can't figure it out. Anyone got any help for me?

Comment: Solved this finally. Updated my package.json with a higher version of npm (2.6+) and ran npm install. Everything updated magically. Got rid of this error and then ran into four more errors that required chmod 777 to get through. Pretty brutal, but probably useful for people who use Digital Ocean. Just remember, change the package.json npm version to something higher than what yo requires (I believe it's like 2.5+?) and then chmod 777 any folder that gets in your way (there were 4).